# Unit testing EJBs on Jboss 4.3?

Tags: jboss, testng, jboss-arquillian

Is there anything similar to `Embedded Glassfish`, where one can unit test EJBs, for `Jboss 4.3 AS`. I have googled and came to know about a tool `Arquillian` and later figured out that it doesnt support Jboss 4.3 container [Check here](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/snapshot/en-US/html_single/#d0e713). Is there any similar open source tool available to unit test EJBs on Jboss 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the URL to the reference guide in your question is "a bit" out of date; please don't refer that since the list of supported containers, as well as other info is out of date. The Arquillian Reference Guide is hosted in [Confluence](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Reference+Guide) where [the list of supported container adapters](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+adapters) is maintained.

Secondly, you're likely to have some success with the JBoss AS 4.2 containers, as reported by other users in the [JBoss Community forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/196745). There is no embedded container available for 4.x, since the embeddable EJB container was born out the EJB 3.1/Java EE 6 specification.

Comment: thank you very much for the info. One more question, is there a way to download Arquillian related jars without use of Maven/ivy? something like zip?

Comment: I dont think that is possible and neither is it recommended. Maven/Ant+Ivy/Gradle is recommended because of the pluggable nature of Arquillian. Every extension of Arquillian has it's own release cycle, so having a dependency management tool is the best way to go about using Arquillian.